# SQL shorten responds time using parallel or with clause

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I have a query that takes 20 min to executed... I remember in one project we used /*+ PARALLEL(T,8) */ or we would use the with clause and  /*+ materialize */ and it would make the query responds time really fast withing seconds. How can I do this to this query?

```
select count(*) from (                          
       select hdr.ACCESS_IND,        
            hdr.SID,    
             hdr.CLLI,    
             hdr.DA,    
             hdr.TAPER_CODE,    
             hdr.CFG_TYPE  as CFG_TYPE,    
             hdr.IP_ADDR,    
             hdr.IOS_VERSION,    
             hdr.ADMIN_STATE,    
             hdr.WIRE_CENTER,    
             substr(hdr.SID_IO_PRI, 1, 8)    PRI_IO_CLLI,    
             substr(hdr.SID_IO_SEC, 1, 8)    SEC_IO_CLLI,    
             hdr.VHO_CLLI ,   
             hdr.CFG_TYPE ,
          --   dtl.MULTIPURPOSE_IND,
             lkup.code3 as shelf_type
     from      RPT_7330_HDR    hdr  
     INNER JOIN   RPT_7330_DTL dtl on hdr.EID = dtl.EID
     INNER JOIN CODE_LKUP2 lkup ON LKUP.CODE1 = hdr.ACCESS_IND
     where    LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING' and  hdr.DT_MODIFIED = (select DT_MODIFIED    
                                from     LS_DT_MODIFIED    
                                where NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR')) n;
```

[image: Here is the explain plan]

Comment: Opps sorry that was a mistake I will editted it thanks for catching that.

Comment: I removed the duplicate filter and added the explain plan

Comment: This is fine. Let me know the record count for RPT_7330_HDR, RPT_7330_DTL, CODE_LKUP2, LS_DT_MODIFIED. Also share the partition details for the tables. Again same question :) How many CPU's? You want all rows or only count??

Comment: RPT_7330_HDR = 79,490,697 partition is DT_MODIFIED; RPT_7330_DTL = 78,854,834 partition is DT_MODIFIED; CODE_LKUP2 = 2320 no partition; LS_DT_MODIFIED = 398 no partition. How do I find the CPUs?

Comment: It sounds like you're treating parallel query and common table expressions (WITH clause) as performance magic bullets, instead of understanding what they actually do, how they work, and what their limitations are. I suggest you visit the docs, which cover parallel query very well. The materialise hint on the common table expression is pretty well described in the docs, but be sure to think about the implications of using it, and understand that it is often redundant for large data sets anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data then

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(DTL,4) */
            HDR.ACCESS_IND,
            HDR.SID,
            HDR.CLLI,
            HDR.DA,
            HDR.TAPER_CODE,
            HDR.CFG_TYPE AS CFG_TYPE,
            HDR.IP_ADDR,
            HDR.IOS_VERSION,
            HDR.ADMIN_STATE,
            HDR.WIRE_CENTER,
            SUBSTR ( HDR.SID_IO_PRI, 1, 8 ) PRI_IO_CLLI,
            SUBSTR ( HDR.SID_IO_SEC, 1, 8 ) SEC_IO_CLLI,
            HDR.VHO_CLLI,
            HDR.CFG_TYPE,
            LKUP.CODE3 AS SHELF_TYPE
       FROM
            RPT_7330_HDR HDR INNER JOIN RPT_7330_DTL DTL ON HDR.EID = DTL.EID
            INNER JOIN CODE_LKUP2 LKUP ON LKUP.CODE1 = HDR.ACCESS_IND
            INNER JOIN LS_DT_MODIFIED ON HDR.DT_MODIFIED = DT_MODIFIED
       WHERE
                LKUP.CATEGORY = 'ACCESS_MAPPING'
            AND NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR';
```

If you want count then

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(DTL,4) */
            COUNT (*)
       FROM
            RPT_7330_HDR HDR INNER JOIN RPT_7330_DTL DTL ON HDR.EID = DTL.EID
            INNER JOIN CODE_LKUP2 LKUP ON LKUP.CODE1 = HDR.ACCESS_IND
            INNER JOIN LS_DT_MODIFIED ON HDR.DT_MODIFIED = DT_MODIFIED
       WHERE
                LKUP.CATEGORY = 'ACCESS_MAPPING'
            AND NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR';
```

**Note:** Hint used on DTL table which is taking more cost for FTS. Number 4 means query fired on 8 CPU's parallely. Identify your pain points from query plan and decide on your hints for parallel or any other. You can also use parallel hint on multiple tables `/*+ PARALLEL(table1 4) PARALLEL(table2 4) PARALLEL(table3 4) PARALLEL(table4 4)*/` . Also This works only on Enterprise edition and not on standard edition.

Comment: `ON HDR.DT_MODIFIED DT_MODIFIED` is not a valid join

Comment: oops.. Typo.. Thanks for spotting

Comment: The first one to get the data was really fast in 1 second the other one to get the count was 4:19 mins... which is better than 20 mins... So we want to use DTL (which is the biggest table and the cost is higher) But how to you determine the integer 4?

Comment: Integer 4 means your query gets run on 8 CPU's.. Its a guesswork.

Comment: Also note that, if you try same query, again and again the result will be faster due to caching. if you want to try adding another table for parallel, you can. The complete dataset returned in 1 second is actually a joke, because it returns only a few rows in your client tool. If you write it somewhere you know the pain.

Comment: @Gio if this is the answer that resolved your issue, please tick the same or upvote helpful answers which would be more polite.

Comment: Couple o' notes ... parallel degree 4 might mean 4 PQ processes, although more commonly it means 8 ... depends on presence of joins and aggregation etc. You're also less likely to get caching benefit from a parallel query as the data blocks generally bypass the SGA buffer cache through the direct read mechanism, though data volumes are usually too high for caching anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, might be faster:

```
  select count(*) 
  from RPT_7330_HDR hdr  
  JOIN LS_DT_MODIFIED LS ON LS.NAME = 'RPT_7330_HDR' AND hdr.DT_MODIFIED = LS.DT_MODIFIED
  JOIN RPT_7330_DTL dtl on hdr.EID = dtl.EID
  JOIN CODE_LKUP2 lkup ON LKUP.CODE1 = hdr.ACCESS_IND AND LKUP.CATEGORY='ACCESS_MAPPING'
```

The SQL engine can optimize JOINS to be parallel if you have the right indexes and such.  It is often able to optimize joins when it can't optimize sub-queries.

Comment: This count was faster it took 3:34 mins... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ ...
```

You do *not* want to use a magic number and you do *not* want to list any objects.

A degree of parallelism of 8 is probably too high on your laptop, yet too low on your production server.  If the query simply specifies `PARALLEL`, Oracle will automatically determine the DOP if it's configured for automatic parallelism.  Or it will default to the number of CPUs * threads per CPU * number of instances.  Judging by all the manuals, features, and whitepapers, Oracle has put a lot of thought into the degree of parallelism.  If you're not going to benchmark it you should trust the defaults.

In 11gR2, when you don't list any objects you use statement level parallelism instead of object level parallelism.  There's not need to try to determine exactly
which objects and access paths needs to be parallelized.  If you change the query or alias names later there's no chance of the hint not working.

Here's a [quick introduction to the parallel hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF51122).  There's also the
[Using Parallel Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel.htm#i1009828) chapter of the VLDB and Partitioning Guide.